# How can I execute a command with parameters that include all files from a given directory?

Tags: bash

I have a 100+ directories each containing a number of files named `title??.abc`, where `??` are numeric and only 2 digits. The title part remains constant. All folders have different number of files and there's no consistent naming scheme for the folders.

I would like the script to get the filenames from a single folder and execute a command like so:

```
mycmd '[' title00.abc title01.abc .... < all files > ']'
```

I've found numerous examples of a for each in loop but I require all filenames to be in a single command line.

Comment: Provide an example of what your input is, as well as what your command is.

Comment: Sorry .... The files are named title_t??.abc ... the directories all have different names with no pattern ....

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
for dir in directory_pattern; do
  cmd '[' "$dir"/title[0-9][0-9].abc ']'
done
```

Assuming all your directories have some consistent naming scheme such that a simple glob can expand to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `find` and `xargs`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "title*.abc" | xargs [cmd]
```

edit: or with interpolation to add the brackets at the end, and with sorting

```
[cmd] "[" $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "title*.abc" | sort) "]"
```

Comment: I tried .. but it does not sort properly ... title18 comes before title12 ... also, how would I add the traiing ']'?

Comment: `does not sort` so pipe it via `| sort |`.

Comment: Updated with sorting and trailing ]

Comment: `$(find -maxdepth 1 | sort)` is overkill. A simple glob `title*.abc` does the same thing.

Comment: Good to know! I use zsh so would use a glob myself but wasn't sure how portable it is